# Redes Sociais em meu app

Tags: android

Bom quero adicionar dois botoes onde o usuário iria compartilhar uma frase no facebook ou twitter com meu aplicativo de link(via aplicativo...), não sei por onde começar.

Comment: Procure pelo SDK do Facebook (ou Twitter) para Android. Lá é um bom começo.

Comment: Ja tentei mais tem coisas avançadas que não entendo ainda, busco exemplos

Comment: Se você acha que alguma coisa em programação está além da sua habilidade, não se intimide. Estude tudo o que for necessário para alcançar o nível de habilidade necessário para chegar lá.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como sugestão, HTML, JavaScript, PhoneGap talvez resolva:

Use o PhoneGap (http://build.phonegap.com) e o Plugin Facebook Connect (https://build.phonegap.com/plugins/257)

Exemplo em:
https://github.com/phonegap-build/FacebookConnect/blob/962eb0a1c07935ff813e28aa9eaa5581f2e10416/README.md

Consulte também o SDK JavaScript do Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart),

Eu acho boa opção você usar o PhoneGap Build online. Para um projeto é gratuito. É mais prático para começar.